# If i map using Hibernate a number-type column database to a var char variable in java,should it give me any errors?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, graniteds

If i map using Hibernate a number-type column database to a var char variable in java,should it give me any errors?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: I've tried it but strangely it does not give me any errors.Logically it should give me errors.